# Set Vuex Store state with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

Is there a way for me to set a Vuex Store with typescript, but have it be empty?

My current code for this is:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    username: string
  },
});
```

But I currently get: "'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here". I know I can then put a string in username, but I require it to be empty.

Comment: What do you mean empty? an empty string, undefined, or null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    strict: true,
    state: {
      username: ""
    },
  });
```

This way username is declared as a string and still empty at the beginning.

Personally I would go the following route though:

```
/* location: '/src/models/state.ts': */
interface IState {
    username?: string;
}

/* location: '/src/store.ts': */
const state: IState = {username: undefined};

export default new Vuex.Store({strict: true, state});
```

This way you can have better typing for your store state and leave the username `undefined` as in your question. You also don't need to remember checking for undefined, as your IDE will remind you that you need to check `state.username !== undefined` whenever you want to use the username as a string.
So consider using an empty string as initial value and not allowing `undefined` by removing the `?` in the interface.